# Some style not working on :after

Tags: html, css

**hello**

I try to style content that is added with `:after` , `color: ;` is overwritten, but `text-decoration: ;` doesn't work.

***code.html***

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .separate-hyphen *:not(:last-child):after {
            content: " -\00a0";
            text-decoration: none;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="separate-hyphen">
        <a href="link1.extension">Link 1</a>
        <a href="link2.extension">Link 2</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***result*** *(it's an image)*

[image]

Comment: border works correctly. What do you want to reach in this case?

Comment: I am sorry, I accidentally used border because I am used to replacing the text decoration with a border to have more control; I edited my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because pseudo element `:after` is rendered *inside* of element, not outside, so of course styling it cannot affect outer container styles:

```
+--------------------+
|         +--------+ |
| Content | :after | |
|         +--------+ |
+--------------------+
```

You need to find another way. Maybe to visually move `:after` outside of its container with absolute positioning:

```css
.separate-hyphen *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.separate-hyphen *:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " -\00a0";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="separate-hyphen">
  <a href="link1.extension">Link 1</a>
  <a href="link2.extension">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I see how this works now; and this technique of yours works. Is this the preferred way? And could the same effect be garnered by replacing the text decoration with a black bottom border on the a element and then putting a white border on the after pseudo element so the black border is hidden behind the white border? when I try to do this they just stack.

Comment: Yes you can overlap pseudo element border over element's one. This is one of the few solutions in this case. Just need to position them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `text-decoration: none` instead of `border:none`.

Comment: This is what I meant to do, sorry; It still doesn't work though, it makes the same output (the image I provided)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #hyphen {
        color: red;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .linkz
      {
        color: red;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      
      #linkcontainer
      {
        border: 3px solid blue;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        width: 135px;
        background-color: #6d6;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="linkcontainer">
        <a href="link1.extension" class="linkz">Link 1</a><a id="hyphen">-</a><a href="link2.extension" class="linkz">Link 2</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

It will work for what I think you want.

Comment: This will remove the border / text-decoration entirely. I was looking for a way to only remove the border / text-decoration from the content that was added at the end of an element using after.

Comment: I updated the snippet. This works? Is beautiful too.

Comment: Thanks for the update; it would work just as well, but unfortunately I only have control over the css where I have to use it. I think I will use this when I can alter the html as well though.

Comment: I meant that I have to develop something but I am not allowed to edit the html there.

Comment: It's ok. Only use JSBin to make tests. :)